# Multiple arrow heads when one of them is Arc Barb

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In this document, I make three arrows: one with a single `Latex` arrow head, one with two `Latex` arrow heads, and one with a single `Arc Barb` arrow head:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
      \draw[-{Latex}{Latex}] (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
      \draw[-{Arc Barb[reversed]}] (0,-2) -- (2,-2);
      %% \draw[-{Latex}{Arc Barb[reversed]}] (0,-3) -- (2,-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works as expected.

However, as soon as I add the fourth arrow with a `Latex` and an `Arc Barb` arrow head, it breaks:

```
! Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'Arc Barb'.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9       \draw[-{Latex}{Arc Barb[reversed]}]
                                              (0,-3) -- (2,-3);
```

How do I combine these two arrow heads? And moreover, in a bit of "learning to fish" effort, why are arrow heads not abstractly composable, i.e. why is it possible that composing `Latex` with `Latex` works, but `Latex` with `Arc Barb` doesn't, when both `Latex` and `Arc Barb` are "of the same type" (i.e. both are arrowheads)?

Comment: They are combinable. Try `\draw[-{Latex}{Stealth}] (0,-3) -- (2,-3);` or `\draw[-{Latex}{Arc Barb}] (0,-4) -- (2,-4);`.

Comment: Considering the Ti*k*Z manual (section 16), I assume that the `reversed` option is meant to be used only once on a tip, and is not allowed for combinations. You can probably add one with `decorations` library in a postaction, if you really need it.

Comment: @SebGlav: I'm using TikZ 3.0.1, and its documentation's section 16.4.1 provides the example `-Stealth[length=5pt] Stealth[length=6pt]` so having separate settings for each head looks like it should work. Unfortunately, even a straight copy-paste of this two-`Stealth`-with-diff-length example errors out when I try to use it...

Comment: Oh, it seems the syntax should be `[-{Stealth[length=5pt] Stealth[length=6pt]}`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the correct syntax for multi-head arrows is to wrap all the arrow heads together into an extra layer of braces:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[-{{Latex} {Arc Barb}[reversed]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good to know! Combining like I did is still OK, but I even didn't think to enclose them into curly braces.

Comment: @SebGlav: I couldn't get the `reversed` part working with your version.